# How to move picturebox with mouse, but with the mouse remaining on it's position?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I had some code to move the control around, but when you reached the end of the screen you had to release your right mouse button, right click on the image again, and drag again, .. repeat..

Now I tried to rewrite the code so the control would move without the mouse being moved. This is what I have for now:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    Dim xx As String = DirectCast(e, MouseEventArgs).Button.ToString
    If xx = "Right" Then
        Dim Px As Point = New Point(Me.Location.X + SplitContainer1.Location.X + SplitContainer1.SplitterDistance + CInt((SplitContainer1.Width - SplitContainer1.SplitterDistance) / 2), Me.Location.Y + SplitContainer1.Location.Y + CInt(SplitContainer1.Height / 2))
        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = Px
        PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Left + (e.X - Px.X)
        PictureBox1.Top = PictureBox1.Top + (e.Y - Px.Y)
    End If
End Sub
```

However the image doesn't move, it returns to it's original position along with the mouse.

How would I make this code move the picturebox without allowing the mouse to change position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I solved it quite easily:

```
Dim TemporaryMousePointerLocation As Point 
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    Static UpdateMouseOnNextMove As Boolean = False ' we need to have an update delay between each mouse move, if we update the position of the mouse each mousemove then there will be no movement
    If DirectCast(e, MouseEventArgs).Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        If UpdateMouseOnNextMove Then
            PictureBox1.Left -= (Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - TemporaryMousePointerLocation.X)
            PictureBox1.Top -= (Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - TemporaryMousePointerLocation.Y)
            Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = TemporaryMousePointerLocation 
            UpdateMouseOnNextMove = False
        Else
            UpdateMouseOnNextMove = True ' allow cursor to move a bit so we can update the position of the mouse
        End If
    Else
        TemporaryMousePointerLocation = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position
    End If
End Sub
```

If there is some better code to use, let me know.

Comment: The best way to treat the guy who is going to take over the maintenance of your code some day: a homicidal manic that knows where you live.  This will set him off.

Comment: the only guy who's going to maintain my code is me :p if this was production stuff I would've programmed more wisely. variable naming etc...